# SQL Server string exec a procedure with output parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exec

How do I use output parameters with Character String Exec?
Consider following query with "standard" syntax:

```
DECLARE @testString nvarchar(50);
EXEC testProcedure  @param1 = @testString OUTPUT
SELECT 'result ' = @testString
go
```

How to re-create *exactly* same result with character string exec, neither

```
EXEC ( 'testProcedure @param1 = @testString OUTPUT' )
```

nor

```
EXEC ( 'testProcedure @param1 = ' + @testString + ' OUTPUT' )
```

seems to work: the result is either `NULL` or `Must declare the scalar variable "@testString"` error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the value as a parameter. Dynamic SQL is executed in new context that is why variable is not visible there.

You should use [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx):

```
DECLARE @testString nvarchar(50);

EXEC dbo.sp_executesql N'EXEC testProcedure @testString OUTPUT',
                       N'@testString nvarchar(50) OUTPUT',
                       @testString OUTPUT;

SELECT 'result ' = @testString;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/TIXU98828)**</kbd>

Comment: Is it possible to return in dynamic SQL something like @a = exec (@sql). @a is coming from return value of proc not output param.