# Dynamic SQL with BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2017 I've tried numerous variations on this effort at dynamic SQL and there is never a result. This is the simplest of my attempts.

```
DECLARE @sql AS nvarchar(500)

SET @sql = N'SELECT @strJSON_Table = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''c:\\json\JSON_download.json'' , SINGLE_CLOB) AS JTable'

SELECT @pintImpID AS ImpID, OtherCol --etc
        INTO temp_JSON_download

        FROM OPENJSON(@strJSON_Table)
            WITH(
                IsSuccessful NVARCHAR(MAx) as JSON,
                Messages NVARCHAR(MAx) as JSON,
                AccreditInfos NVARCHAR(MAx) as JSON
                ) AS TableA

-- followed by a very extensive (to my standard) set of statements the break out the json into different tables.
```

I am aiming for the SQL that is executed to be like this

```
SELECT @strJSON_Table = BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\\json\JSON_download.json', SINGLE_CLOB) AS JTable
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi meridian, have you tried with `SINGLE_BLOB` instead?

Comment: You can't assign an outer variable inside dynamic SQL.

Comment: But you *can* parametrise said variable and also define it as an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft One would assume that the OP would get an error message if the variable wasn't defined? Perhaps this is an excerpt in a larger script, though I'm probably wrong and not seeing something.

Comment: Though I don't see why the above SQL is being set to a variable in the first place; normally you would do that for dynamic SQL but there is nothing dynamic about the above. The above perhaps doesn't reflect the whole problem.

Comment: What about just `SELECT BulkColumn` what are you trying to achieve, do you need it to be inserted into a variable?

Comment: Yes, apologies, there is a really long select into following the snippet I originally posted. I'll edit the original post.

Comment: TT, the second section of sql shows the code that works as non-dynamic sql, hard coded path, and it uses SINGLE_CLOB.

Comment: Larnu, in this example I used a hard coded path to the file, because even that doesn't work as dynamic sql. The intent is to replace the hard coded path with a variable.

Comment: David Browne, I bet your comment about 'outer variable' is the issue. Is that the @strJSON_Table bit? And if so what Larnu wrote about parameters and OUTPUT would be the way forward?

Comment: Rather than an incomplete script, give us a meaningful and representative example, @meridian .

Comment: The JSON and crossapply stuff is really outside my skillset. I don't think I can properly reduce the code to something realistic, unfortunately. I wish I could, and appreciate everyone trying to help out.

Comment: Not near a Windows machine to check currently, but in the past doubled backslashes in local filesystem paths have been a problem. Does changing from `'c:\\json\JSON_download.json'` to `'c:\json\JSON_download.json'` make a difference?

Comment: Thank you AlwaysLearning. A good suggestion; I'd wondered about the doubled backslashes but never experimented with them. However using a single didn't impact the outcome. Of course it could be that plus something else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server string exec a procedure with output parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968082/sql-server-string-exec-a-procedure-with-output-parameter)